# Turning on 'Experimental Web Platform Features' in OBS Browser

Tags: chromium, obs-studio

I am trying to use backdrop-filter in an info webpage that I am building for streaming. I would like to use backdrop-filter to blur a part of an HTML5 canvas of the website.

If my knowledge is correct, OBS Browser implements Chromium and in Chromium this can be turned on with the Experimental Web Platform Features flag.

Is there a way to turn this on in OBS Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out finally: I had to add the following to the command line arguments:  `--enable-experimental-web-platform-features`

I also need webgl support, so the final shortcut looks like this for me:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe" --enable-gpu --enable-experimental-web-platform-features
```

Comment: Is this still working for you? I've copied `"C:\Program Files (x86)\obs-studio\bin\64bit\obs64.exe" --enable-gpu --enable-experimental-web-platform-features` to my short cut and still have the initial issue on https://github.com/obsproject/obs-browser/issues/41

Comment: Hi, yes it still works for me. I just tested both OBS 20.1.3 and 21.1.0 and both versions worked for me.

Comment: Hmm okay. I use 21.1.0 on Windows and accessing http://get.webgl.org/ through OBS for instance gives me error. I run my shortcut with your example but no dice. Do you know which release you are using? https://github.com/obsproject/obs-browser/releases

Comment: Okay this issue seems to be limited to my specific Windows 10 computer. My Windows 7 computer works accordingly

Comment: Hey, do you still need help? Sorry was occupied lately

Comment: I kinda went a totally different direction. The CEF plugin was way to unstable for what I was triyng to do so going with a Window capture solution

Comment: Glad you worked out at the end. I've been having performance issues with CAF but it's borderline good enough :D